# Facebook API integration with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to integrate Facebook API with my Rails application.

Here I can login with Facebook successfully and can fetch name, email and profile pic.

I have used gem : `gem ‘omniauth-facebook’`

But now I want to fetch all posts from the timeline of Facebook user.

Please guide me for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add things that you've already tried and code related to it?

Comment: yeah, this is way too broad right now. did you check out the api reference? btw, it is not possible to get all posts from the timeline, you can only get posts of the authorized user.

Comment: @AnujKhandelwal You can see https://github.com/pmokariya/social-media-intigration-rails

Comment: always include relevant information in the question, NEVER in comments

Comment: anyway, please point us to the location in your code where you have tried to fetch posts. also, add debug info if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create one sample application on Facebook developer center in order to get AppId and AppSecret for authentication. Also, you can give few permission there in your profile of developers account.
You can refer to following Blog : https://medium.com/@trydelight/facebook-authentication-with-devise-5b53d2f664ed